# Lock formulas in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm creating a table for a friend to input information but he is not very good at computers. I had him work on a table in Excel and locked the page and this worked great but now I want to check his work and doing this online is the better option.

How may I lock a formula in a Google spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1):

I right-clicked on a cell (or several cells) in Google Docs Spreadsheets and there is an option "Name and Protect range"
I assume you have seen this, and doesn't suit your needs?
Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to set up a Google Form, and have him enter the data there:  that means he cannot even see the formulas.